# Multiplication of matricees

Tags: linear-algebra

This is an example in Serge Lang "Introduction to Linear Algebra", page 48. I try to multiply these two $2$x$3$ and $3$x$2$ matrices but fail to obtain the result as mentioned in the text.

I have: 
$
\left( \begin{array}{cc}
2 & 1 & 5\\
1 & 3 & 2
\end{array} \right)
%
\left( \begin{array}{c}
3 & 4 \\
-1 & 2 \\
2 & 1
\end{array} \right)
=\left( \begin{array}{c}
15 & 30 \\
4 & 2
\end{array} \right)
$

Serge's result is, however:

$
\left( \begin{array}{cc}
2 & 1 & 5\\
1 & 3 & 2
\end{array} \right)
%
\left( \begin{array}{c}
3 & 4 \\
-1 & 2 \\
2 & 1
\end{array} \right)
=\left( \begin{array}{c}
15 & 15 \\
4 & 2
\end{array} \right)
$

Where did I do wrong?

Comment: Double-check your computation of the top right  $30$ ...

Comment: Can you explain how did you get this $30$? It really should be $15$.

Comment: You need to show us the details of your calculations before we can tell you where you went wrong. Also, Serge's answer is correct.

Comment: I multiply the first row of the matrix with the first column of the second matrix, then the first row of the first matrix with the second column of the second matrix, then the second row of the first matrix with the second colum of the second matrix.

Comment: please show how you "multiply the first row of the first matrix with the second column of the second matrix"

Comment: So for the top $30$, I have ($2$x$4$) + ($1$x$2$) + ($5$x$4$) = $8+2+9=30$

Comment: It should be $2\times4+1\times2+5\times1=8+2+5=15$, and by the way $8+2+9=19$

Comment: Oh I see, a small computational mistake on my part, thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**

$$\left(\begin{array}{}\color{blue }2&\color{red }1&\color{green }5\end{array} \right)  \cdot \left(\begin{array}{}\color{blue }4\\ \color{red }2 \\ \color{green }1\end{array} \right)=\color{blue }{2\cdot 4}+\color{red }{1\cdot 2}+\color{green }{5\cdot 1}=\color{blue }8+\color{red }2+\color{green }5=15$$

Answer (score 1):

We have

$$\left( \begin{array}{cc}
\color{red}{2} & \color{red}{1} & \color{red}{5}\\
1 & 3 & 2
\end{array} \right)
%
\left( \begin{array}{c}
3 & \color{red}{4} \\
-1 & \color{red}{2} \\
2 & \color{red}{1}
\end{array} \right)
=\left( \begin{array}{c}
15 & \color{red}{15} \\
4 & 12
\end{array} \right)$$

that is $2\cdot 4+1\cdot 2+5\cdot 1=8+2+5=15$.

Comment: In the result matrix, how was "2" obtained please? I got 12 instead.

Comment: We are multipling the first row of the matrix on the LHS that is $(2,1,5)$ times the second column vector of the matrix on the RHS  that is $(4,2,1$ therefore by dot product $$(2,1,5)\cdot (4,2,1)=8+2+5=15$$

Comment: @NoChance Yes of course you are right! I didn't check that after copy and past since I was focused only in the red part!

Answer (score 1):

My answer is a different. Notice the entry $a_{22}$ in the result.
[image]